# Gestures Beta app stopped working?

Tags: apps, lumia-520, lumia-denim-update

I was using **[Gestures Beta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/gestures-beta/9wzdncrcx3n9)** on my phone for a long time, one day it just stopped responding.How can I make this thing work again ?

I tried reinstalling the application but still, no response..!
 So, How can I make this app work again? 
I am 100% sure it's not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is in beta stage. So there may be lot of bugs in this app.
You can only try installing it again after it is updated to latest version.